# How to Add JUnit Results to Tycho Built JAR

Tags: maven, tycho

We are using Maven and sometimes Tycho, and I want to put the results of the JUnit tests into the resulting JARs.

With Maven, that's easy. I just added the following to the *pom.xml*:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>target/</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>surefire-reports/*.*</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

The `test` phase is before the `package` phase, so all is well.

For Tycho however, tests are executed after the `package` phase (because they are executed in the `verify` phase for some reason). The phase cannot be changed either (see [bug 440094](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=440094)).

So the only alternative is to build another JAR after the `verify` phase:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>verification-doc</classifier>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/surefire-reports/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, it does not work. Neither the folder nor the files are added. My guess was that it's because of the `include` tag points to the source folders, so I tried:

```
<include>${project.build.outputDirectory}/../surefire-reports/*.*</include>
<include>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/*.*</include>
```

Which did not work either?

So how do I add JUnit test results to the JAR of a Tycho build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the directory of the `maven-bundle-plugin` like this:

```
<configuration>
    <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}</classesDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>surefire-reports/*</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
```